# Create a directory with connection to my android application

Tags: java, android

I see almost every android application has its own data storage folder in sdcard/Android/data....

How to create 1 such folder and use it?

Sample photo

[Sample photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsnXm.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

why won't you start with DOC reading?

all basic informations you have in here: [Data and file storage overview](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage)

you are asking about app-specific directories, doc in here: [Access app-specific files](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific). in short: you have to use [`getExternalFilesDir()`](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific#external-access-files) method for creating folders for your files

also be aware about [Scoped storage](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage), but you already want to keep files in proper, app-specific place, which is mandatory on devices with forced Scoped storage